# Build web page and keep all data on 1 page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, css, dom

I have a task to build a webpage that displays 3 even columns of data (first name last name) and always keeps the information on 1 screen (no scrolling).  As more names are added, the font gets smaller.  Less names, larger font.  This will be displayed on only 1 screen and browser type.

The back end is running to query data from a BOSH server and display the names in 1 column on the web page.  From a design perspective using html/css/js, can anyone recommend an approach?  I'm not looking for specific code so much as a methodology before I dive in.

Comment: Are you anticipating a fixed screen size? This doesn't strike me as a realistic goal.

Comment: Is this for like, a school project?  If it's for a client and your boss wants it this way you should consider approaching him and telling him this isn't really realistic.  At some point there would be enough data to cause the font size to become too small to be legible, which is a problem, that's kind of why scrolling was invented, the digital alternative to turning the page.

Comment: Ha!  Fair enough on both comments.  It is for the boss and I agree the task is a little obscure but I think there's a way to do this without getting too kluge.  I should have said there is somewhat of a high/low watermark on the data, probably between 50-200 results.  My initial thought was to get the total results from my server query, divide by 3 and then have some type of font-size mapping to the results with a min and max font size so if there are too many we think of a better solution and if there are less than usual we don't get too big on the font size.  Whattaya think?

Comment: @Mathletics - yes, fixed screen size.